# Deploying application using SQL Server CE 4.0 SP1 using "Any CPU"

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dll, sql-server-ce

I am planning to create an application which uses SQL Server CE 4.0 SP1 using private deployment.So now i am planning to use private deployment. So all the dll must be included in the project as explained [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173298(v=sql.110).aspx).

But I tried just adding all dll from my XP PC (32 bit) and not added any 64 bit dlls (but it was mentioned to add 64 bit dlls). Then i set platform to "Any CPU". After building application i tried running my application in a 64 bit PC and it worked properly!!! I was expecting it would give error as i have not included 64 bit dlls.

Then I used isWow64Process api to check whether the application is really running on 64 bit. It returned false when i set "any cpu" and 64 bit, means it runs on 64 bit.When i set to x86 it returns true which means it is running under wow64(as 32 bit process). If I set it to x64 it works properly in 64 bit pc, but SQL Server CE dlls are of 32 bit. why does this happen? My plan is to use "Any cpu" so that it works as 32 bit in 32 bit PC and 64 bit process in 64 bit pc. So what i am missing. Why does it work even if i set any cpu or x64?

**EDIT:**

I have found the reason why it was working on 64 bit PC.its because the pc already had SQL CE 4.0 SP1 installed. So application used dll from installed path instead of using files from app path where it had 32 bit dll which dont support 64 bit application(any cpu).

But now I am following the link mentioned above and added x86 and AMD64(not x64 as mentioned in that link) folder and corresponding dlls and Microsoft.VC90.CRT dlls properly, it works properly on windows 7(.net 3.5 by default- sql ce is not installed). In windows XP sp3 (fresh install with only OS)  I installed .net 2.0  and then run my application. It worked!!

1) So does SQL CE 4.0 SP1 private deployment require .net 3.5? Will it cause any other problem if i use only .net 2.0?

2)I found like we need to modify app.config to refer to the Private ADO.NET provider, which has assembly version 4.0.0.1, not 4.0.0.0 as the on in the GAC which is mentioned [here](http://erikej.blogspot.in/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html) I have not done this and it and my application worked properly. So is it required to do? If i don't add it will it cause error in any .net framework?

3) I have not included System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity dll. I am using SqlCeConnection to connect to database. So is there any need of adding System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity dll? Also  some where i found like this dll require .net 3.5 so microsoft recommends installing .net 3.5 for private deployment of SQL CE 4.0 SP1(related to my 1st question)?

You can download my project [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2B635F7D896B131!173&authkey=!AIW3jFulILbBY54&ithint=file%2czip)

Comment: Sounds like ypur process is always a 32 bit process. Are you using .net 4,5 and have the Prefer 32 bit option set?

Comment: No. i am using VS 2010. it has any cpu option. "Prefer 32 bit " option is only in vs 2012 and above.I have made changes to my question.plz check .isWow64Process  returning proper and when i set "Any cpu" or 64 it is running as 64 bit process only.